# C++14 std::array implementation

Tags: c++, array, reinventing-the-wheel

I invested an hour or so to reimplement the C++ header `<array>`. Most stuff is in the namespace `my_std`, but `tuple_size`, etc. are not, otherwise they are useless. I aimed for **C++14**.

One caveat: the `array<T, N>::swap` member function's noexcept specification is too complicated, and I chose not to reimplement the `std::is_nothrow_swappable` trait which is not available prior to C++17.

I used [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/array) as a reference. I did not check everything, though, and there may be nonconforming stuff or stuff taken from C++17. Feel free to tell me :)

Here is my code, within 300 lines: (excluding blank lines and comments)

```
// array.hpp
// C++14 std::array implementation

#ifndef INC_ARRAY_HPP_JCr9Lp1ED0
#define INC_ARRAY_HPP_JCr9Lp1ED0

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace my_std {

    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    struct array {
    private:
        void error() const
        {
            throw std::out_of_range{ "array out of range" };
        }

    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = T&;
        using const_reference = const T&;
        using pointer = T*;
        using const_pointer = const T*;
        using iterator = T*;
        using const_iterator = const T*;
        using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
        using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

        constexpr bool empty() const noexcept
        {
            return N == 0;
        }
        constexpr size_type size() const noexcept
        {
            return N;
        }
        constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept
        {
            return N;
        }

        T& at(std::size_t pos)
        {
            if (pos >= N)
                this->error();
            return elems[pos];
        }
        constexpr const T& at(std::size_t pos) const
        {
            if (pos >= N)
                this->error();
            return elems[pos];
        }
        T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
        {
            return elems[pos];
        }
        constexpr const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
        {
            return elems[pos];
        }

        T& front()
        {
            return elems[0];
        }
        constexpr const T& front() const
        {
            return elems[0];
        }
        T& back()
        {
            return elems[N - 1];
        }
        constexpr const T& back() const
        {
            return elems[N - 1];
        }

        T* data() noexcept
        {
            return elems;
        }
        constexpr const T* data() const noexcept
        {
            return elems;
        }

        T* begin() noexcept
        {
            return elems;
        }
        const T* begin() const noexcept
        {
            return elems;
        }
        const T* cbegin() const noexcept
        {
            return elems;
        }

        T* end() noexcept
        {
            return begin() + N;
        }
        const T* end() const noexcept
        {
            return begin() + N;
        }
        const T* cend() const noexcept
        {
            return begin() + N;
        }

        auto rbegin() noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }
        auto rbegin() const noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }
        auto crbegin() const noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }

        auto rend() noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }
        auto rend() const noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }
        auto crend() const noexcept
        {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }

        void fill(const T& value)
        {
            std::fill_n(elems, N, value);
        }

        /*
        Note: is_nothrow_swappable_v
        is not available prior to C++17.
        I am not going to the trouble to
        implement it from scratch.
        So the noexcept specification of swap
        is left unimplemented.
        */
        void swap(array& other) /*noexcept(std::is_swappable_v<T>)*/
        {
            std::swap_ranges(begin(), end(), other.begin());
        }

        T elems[N];
    };

    template <class T>
    struct array<T, 0> {
    private:
        void error() const
        {
            throw std::out_of_range{ "array out of range" };
        }

    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = T&;
        using const_reference = const T&;
        using pointer = T*;
        using const_pointer = const T*;
        using iterator = T*;
        using const_iterator = const T*;
        using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
        using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

        constexpr bool           empty() const noexcept { return true; }
        constexpr std::size_t     size() const noexcept { return 0; }
        constexpr std::size_t max_size() const noexcept { return 0; }

                        T&         at(std::size_t pos) { this->error(); }
        constexpr const T&         at(std::size_t pos) const { this->error(); }
                        T& operator[](std::size_t pos) { this->error(); }
        constexpr const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const { this->error(); }

                        T& front()                { this->error(); }
        constexpr const T& front() const          { this->error(); }
                        T&  back()                { this->error(); }
        constexpr const T&  back() const          { this->error(); }
                        T*  data()       noexcept { return nullptr; }
        constexpr const T*  data() const noexcept { return nullptr; }

              T*   begin()       noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*   begin() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*  cbegin() const noexcept { return nullptr; }

              T*     end()       noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*     end() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*    cend() const noexcept { return nullptr; }

              T*  rbegin()       noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*  rbegin() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T* crbegin() const noexcept { return nullptr; }

              T*    rend()       noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*    rend() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
        const T*   crend() const noexcept { return nullptr; }

        void fill(const T& value) {}
        void swap(array& other) noexcept {}
    };

    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator==(const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
                          rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator!=(const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator< (const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
                                            rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator<=(const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return !(rhs < lhs);
    }
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator> (const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return rhs < lhs;
    }
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    inline bool operator>=(const array<T, N>& lhs,
                           const array<T, N>& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs < rhs);
    }

    template <std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr T& get(array<T, N>& a) noexcept
    {
        return a[I];
    }
    template <std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr T&& get(array<T, N>&& a) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<T&&>(a[I]);
    }
    template <std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr const T& get(const array<T, N>& a) noexcept
    {
        return a[I];
    }

    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    void swap(array<T, N>& lhs, array<T, N>& rhs)
        noexcept(noexcept(lhs.swap(rhs)))
    {
        return lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
}

namespace std {
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    class tuple_size<my_std::array<T, N>>
        :public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> {
    };
    template <std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<I, my_std::array<T, N>> {
        using type = T;
    };
}

#endif
```

The naming for the include guard just contains a random string to avoid name clashes. Generally, I don't like (C++) macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define all the types why not use them?

```
    const T* begin() const noexcept

    // More informative to write:

    const_iterator begin() const noexcept
```

Comment: Good point! I ought to have used the type aliases I have defined to improve readability instead of littering with “magic types.” I accepted this, but other suggestions are also welcomed ;)

Comment: If you look at my other reviews you will see I usually take code apart piece by piece. But don't see anything else worth commenting on. But it is a very simple bit of code. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> One caveat: the `array<T, N>::swap` member function's `noexcept` specification is too complicated, and I chose not to reimplement the `std::is_nothrow_swappable` trait which is not available prior to C++17.

If a type trait doesn't exist, write your own. C++11/14 overlooked a lot of library features that didn't require language support when they were added in 17. `is_nothrow_swappable` is one of those library features (is also 3 simple structs to test).

> I used cppreference as a reference. I did not check everything, though, and there may be nonconforming stuff or stuff taken from C++17. Feel free to tell me :)

You should use the C++14 standard or a draft version close to the final C++14 standard. [N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/array) was the first draft after C++14 was published.

---

```
        void error() const
        {
            throw std::out_of_range{ "array out of range" };
        }
```

Your function could be better named here. I'd even consider generalizing it to take any `const char*` message and make it a free function.

---

```
        constexpr bool empty() const noexcept
        {
            return N == 0;
        }
```

Since you specialize the case where `N` is \$0\$, this function will always return false.

---

Comment: Thank you! I was just too lazy to implement the `is_nothrow_swappable`. About `<initializer_list>`: that's required by the standard.

Comment: Are you confusing the *initializer clauses* of an aggregate *initializer list* (`array a = { initializer list }`) with `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: I know that `std::initializer_list` is not necessary. But the standard requires that `<array>` includes `<initializer_list>`.

Comment: Look: http://eel.is/c++draft/array.syn

Comment: Gotcha, skipped over the synopsis. Removed from the answer.

Comment: You can find a list of publicly available versions of the draft standard here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/14065

Answer (score 1):

Another point: instead of

```
if (pos >= N)
    this->error();
```

it is sufficient to do

```
if (pos >= N)
    error();
```

since the `this->` is redundant.